# PC wont boot after adding graphics card

Tags: boot, graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply

This is my PC config:

- Gigabyte [GA-H61M-DS2](http://www.gigabyte.in/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4197#ov)
- i3 2100 CPU
- 2 x 4GB Adata DDR3 RAM
- 300 Watt SMPS (PSU)
- 160 GB Adata SSD
- 500 GB SATA 5400RPM Seagate
- 40 GB SATA 5400RPM Samsung

I have been using this PC for over a year, with absolutely no issues. 
I decided to add a graphics card so I could hook up another monitor to extend my display.

I got a [Zotac geforce gt 610 synergy edition 2GB](http://www.zotac.com/in/products/graphics-cards/geforce-600-series/gt-610/product/gt-610/detail/geforce-gt-610-synergy-edition-2gb/sort/starttime/order/DESC/amount/10/section/specifications.html), hooked it up but when I tried to start the pc it just showed me the motherboard logo screen. nothing after that. When I tried to boot again a couple of times it gave me a 1 long beep and 2 short beeps.

My system uses an AMI Bios where [1 long 2 short beeps](http://www.technick.net/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=guide_beep_codes#beepmain) means:

> Failure in video system: a checksum error was encountered in video
>   BIOS ROM, or a horizontal retrace failure has been encountered.

**Q:** Is this because of my PSU?

I am not sure, because the card specifications say min 300 Watts PSU (and max 29 Watt used), and I have that.

Also my motherboard has only one PCIe x16

I tried removing the graphics card and going back to my onboard graphics, the strange thing that I see is, it just waits on the Motherboard logo, until I press F12 and select the hard disk to boot too.

Comment: Did you try reseating the video card?

Comment: @DavidPostill You may want to reread that ;) "1 long beep and 2 short beep：Graphic card error"

Comment: @FastEthernet Oops. Yes I misread it. Your comment is correct. I Will delete mine ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill  i edited the question to add a few more details.

Comment: @AsifBalgar It sounds as if either the new card has a problem, or the PCIe connector or the copper traces to it are damaged, or the card is not properly seated in the connector. 

Thus: 
1) Try removing and reseating the card. 
2) Try another card in the same x16 slot. 
3) Try the card in another system.

PS: That card draws a maximum of 29 Watt. Your PSU should be more than capable of supplying that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across posts in forums where some users experienced trouble getting their graphics cards with the AMI F7 BIOS, which was exactly what I was using.

Updated the BIOS to F9 and it started to work!